# Unable to display Users from Specific SP Group in People part in SharePoint Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have a requirement to display the User profile details from a specific SP group in modern page.

I tried using People Web part available in modern site, but it does not give such option to choose the SP Group from where it will display the User profiles.

The SP group membership is frequently changing, so not an option of selecting specific user profiles in the people web part.

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible using People web part in SharePoint Online. You have to add user profiles manually in [people web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05).

For your requirement, you have to create a custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) solution, which will fetch the user details from SharePoint group and show them on page.

Check below SPFx samples created by community members. These will help you with developing UI and setting people card (`PersonaCard`) like SharePoint OOTB web part.

1. [People Directory](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-people-directory)
2. [Microsoft Graph People Search](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-msgraph-peoplesearch)

Comment: Hi @Kailash, does this answers you question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with similar question in future. Also, the question will be removed from "Unanswered questions" list.